# Need some guidance on UITabbarController

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitabbarcontroller

I'm about to start my first iOS app using `UITabBarController`. before i start i would like to clear some things-
**1.** If app has login screen then how we launch app with login screen(tab bar is not part of login screen, it will come after user successfully logged in)
**2.** And actual question is, if app has home screen that is not part of tab bar(tab bar will be shown on home screen but by defoult no tab bar button is selected at home).

I read some tutorial and those shows that when app is lounched by default first item of tab bar is selected.
Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: read the Apple Human Interface Guideline (HIG) document for design guidance

Answer (score 0):

Your rootViewController should be a UINavigationController with the LoginScreen as rootViewController, then you can navigate to a UITabBarViewController as the target of the navigation.
After navigating to the TabBar, you can hide tha navBar:

```
[navController.navigationBar setHidden: YES];
```